# Is there any way to initialize a new user profile without logging in from the administrator account?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, login, user-profiles, user

Let's say I'm logged in to this Windows machine with administrator privileges. Once adding a new user, the initial login with the account takes some time. After taking the time, I can quickly login with that account.

Now I'd like to know if there's any possible way to reduce the time that it takes to login. I suppose it's kind of an inevitable period of time for the OS, initializing environments and all, but I doubt the procedure must be done by the user who's trying to login to the system for the first time. How great it would be if the administrator could do the job for the other users!

So, I'd really like to ask like the title written above. I'm expecting some commands to run from the command-line so that the initializing can be used in most default Windows environments.

e.g.:

```
C:\>net user NEWUSER newpass /ADD
C:\>net user NEWUSER newpass /initialize (?)
```

You see what I'm looking for. If there's any way to initialize this newly created user profile so it wouldn't take so much time to login for the first time later.

Comment: Initializing a new user involves copying from default user, you could instead [clone a user profile](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+clone+user+profile) with your settings applied, but that has pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to use this successfully. But it requires knowing their password:

`runas /env /profile /user:<domain>\<username> cmd.exe`